# reset dialog box values once its closed using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

i have a code which shows a set of high and low values from a database. I refresh the the table each second using jquery. so the values in the table changes each second.

so when a user clicks it shows a detail of the values relevant to the row that was clicked in a dialog box and its updated live according to the values that are set in the row.

the problem im having is, when i click on the link the dialog box opens and the high and low values are shown. but when i close the dialog box and click on a different row, it shows the previous high and low values plus the newly clicked row values. when i close and click on a different row, it shows the previous values and the new one.

below is my js code

```
$(document).on("click",".high",function() {
    var sym = $(this).closest('tr').children('td.symbol').text();
    var high = $("#"+sym).closest('tr').children('td.high').text();
    var low = $("#"+sym).closest('tr').children('td.low').text();

    setInterval(function(){
        $('#high').html($("#"+sym).closest('tr').children('td.high').text());
        $('#low').html($("#"+sym).closest('tr').children('td.low').text());
    }, 1000);

    $( "#dialog" ).dialog();
});
```

how do i reset the values so once the dialog box is closed on the next click it shows only the relevant values in that row?

**edit**

the html

the symbol gives values such as CPS, ARP, IRSQ, DEML...

```
<tr id="'.$rate->Symbol.'">
       <td class="symbol">'.$rate->Symbol.'</td>
            <td class="high">
                 <a class="high">'.$rate->high.'</a>
            </td>
            <td class="low">
                <a class="low">'.$rate->low.'</a>
            </td>
            <td>
                 '.$value.'
            </td>
            <td>
               '.$current_time.'
            </td>
      </tr>
```

Comment: need to show row markup. We don't know what `$("#"+sym)` is. Suggest you create a demo that replicates problem

Comment: @charlietfl i have added the HTML `$("#"+sym)` is the row ID

Comment: if that's the case why is `closest('tr')` used?

Comment: @charlietfl if i remove that and add `td` it doesnt work. I think the problem is with `setInterval` i just put an alert box inside that once i click and close the dialog, the `setInterval` seems to be executing. is there a way to completely stop and clear the existing values once the dialog box is closed?

Comment: ah yes, you need to use close event of dialog to clear the setInterval or it will run indefinitely. See dialog docs for close event

Comment: @charlietfl i assigned `setInterval` to a variable and added `close: function() { clearInterval(interval);},` but it doesnt seem to stop it

Comment: create a demo that replicates problem in jsfiddle.net. Also you wait one second to update values , should update them on open also

Comment: @charlietfl please check this http://jsfiddle.net/livewirerules/zknhd6xq/1/

Comment: something like this? http://jsfiddle.net/zknhd6xq/2/ You didn't declare variable `interval` in your code so `clearInterval` had nothing to clear

Comment: @charlietfl bt the problem is that if you click on the first high value and then close the dialog box and then click on the 2nd high value. on that dialog box it shows both values. if you repeat by closing and clicking again it keeps on showing the old and new values

Comment: ok, wasn't clearing the old one for some reason, try this  http://jsfiddle.net/zknhd6xq/3/